# "Proof" of $0=1$ in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, natural-numbers

Ok, so here is a proof of "$0 = 1$" I came up with today. You can do in set-theory, where natural numbers are [defined in the usual way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers).

**Proof:** Let $\mathsf{Succ}$ be the function that takes any natural number and adds one to it. Then we have $\mathsf{Succ}(0) = 1$. The image of $\mathsf{Succ}$ on the empty set is of course empty; so we have $\mathsf{Succ}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ and since by our definition of the natural numbers $0 = \emptyset$ this means $\mathsf{Succ}(0)= 0$. This gets us $0 = 1$ as desired. $\Box$

I think the mistake is subtle and I am interested to see what gets pointed out.

---

If you want a hint:

> It abuses some conventional notation which leads to problems here.

Comment: Is the function defined on Natural Numbers ?? Because in that case f(0) is not defined as 0 is not in the set of natural numbers

Comment: Yes it is defined as the natrual numbers. To be more precise $\mathsf{Succ} = \{ ~(n, n \cup \{ n \} ) ~\vert ~n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ where $\mathbb{N}$ is defined as stated in the link.

Comment: So in that case how is S(0) defined ?? 0 is not a natural number

Comment: @Ayush Jain In set theory $0$ is usually defined to be a natural number. (unlike the other branches of mathematics)

Comment: @Mark Oh alright ! I wasn't knowing this. Thanks

Comment: How would you justify your statement that "$\operatorname{Succ}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about mathematics, but rather a puzzle presented to the audience.  It doesn't belong here, but might be more appropriate for [puzzling.se].

Comment: I think it has to do with the issues discussed by the author of this response https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1265512/399263 at the end, about inconsistencies between $x$ and $\{x\}$ and $f$ and $f_*$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a function $f: A \to B$,

we use the notation $f(...)$ for two different things:

1. If $a\in A$, then $f(a)$ is the element of $B$ to which the element $a$ is mapped.
2. If $S\subseteq A$, then $f(S)$ is defined as $f(S)=\{f(s)|s\in S\}$.

---

You mix the two things up when you say that $\mathsf{Succ}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$. The statement is only true under interpretation (2) above, but you use it as if it was true under interpretation (1).

Under interpretation 1, $f(\emptyset) = \{\emptyset\}$.

---

To use unambiguous symbols, let's write functions as what they really are: **relations**.

Every function $f:A\to B$ is in fact a relation, i.e. a subset of $A\times B$, which satisfies the property that if $(a, b_1)\in f$ and $(a, b_2)\in f$, then $b_1=b_2$. The usual shorthand for $(a, b)\in f$ is $f(a)=b$, but in this case, the shorthand can cause confusion, so we will not use it.

We can still use the expression $f(S)$ for what it was before, so we can say that $f(S)=\{b| (a, b)\in f \land a\in S\}$.

OK, with these definitions, let's rewrite the "proof" and see the error jump out at us:

---

> **Proof:** Let $\mathsf{Succ}$ be the function that takes any natural number and adds one to it. Then we have $(0, 1)\in \mathsf{Succ}$.
> The image of $\mathsf{Succ}$ on the empty set is of course empty; so we have $\mathsf{Succ}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ and since by our definition of the natural numbers $0 = \emptyset$ this means $(0,0)\in \mathsf{Succ}$. This gets us $0 = 1$ as desired. $\Box$

The error in reasoning is clear now. The (true) statement
$$\mathsf{Succ}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$$ is **not** the same as the (untrue) statement $$(\emptyset, \emptyset)\in\mathsf{Succ},$$ but in the final sentence, that's exactly what is assumed.

Comment: How common is notation (2)? I hardly ever see sets as arguments of functions like $f(\mathbb{N})$ or $f(\{1,2,3\})$ (except I suppose $2^{\mathbb{N}}$) so I would only have assumed that notation (1) was intended. Or is this mainly a set theory thing?

Comment: @Jam Notation 2 is fairly common. For example, in tolology, a map is open if and only if $f(O)$ is open for every open set $O$.

Comment: In contexts where some elements of the domain of $f$ are also subsets of that domain, the ambiguity is often avoided by using $f(x)$ for meaning (1) and $f[x]$ for meaning (2).  So in the present question, Succ$(0)=1$ while Succ$[0]=0$.

Comment: Sometimes $f''x$ is also used for meaning 2. (And sometimes $f'x$ for meaning 1, though that's more antiquated.)